# Issues migrating from v1beta to v1 for kubernetes ingress

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

In my firm our Kubernetes Cluster was recently updated to 1.22+ and we are using AKS. So I had to change the manifest of our ingress yaml file which was using : networking.k8s.io/v1beta1, to be compliant to the new apiVersion : networking.k8s.io/v1

This is the earlier manifest for the ingress file :

```
{{- if .Values.ingress.enabled -}}
{{- $fullName := include "amroingress.fullname" . -}}
{{- $svcPort := .Values.service.port -}}
{{- if semverCompare ">=1.14-0" .Capabilities.KubeVersion.GitVersion -}}
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
{{- else -}}
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
{{- end }}
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ $fullName }}
  labels:
    {{- include "amroingress.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
  {{- with .Values.ingress.annotations }}
  annotations:
    {{- toYaml . | nindent 4 }}
  {{- end }}
spec:
  {{- if .Values.ingress.tls }}
  tls:
    {{- range .Values.ingress.tls }}
    - hosts:
        {{- range .hosts }}
        - {{ . | quote }}
        {{- end }}
      secretName: {{ .secretName }}
    {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
  rules:
    {{- range .Values.ingress.hosts }}
    - host: {{ .host | quote }}
      http:
        paths:
          #{{- range .paths }}
          #- path: {{ . }}
          #  backend:
          #    serviceName: {{ $fullName }}
          #    servicePort: {{ $svcPort }}
          #{{- end }}
          - path: /callista/?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: amro-amroingress
              servicePort: 8080
    {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
```

and after my changes it looks like this:

```
{{- if .Values.ingress.enabled -}}
{{- $fullName := include "amroingress.fullname" . -}}
{{- $svcPort := .Values.service.port -}}
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
{{- end }}
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ include "amroingress.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    {{- include "amroingress.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
  {{- with .Values.ingress.annotations }}
  annotations:
    {{- toYaml . | nindent 4 }}
  {{- end }}
spec:
  {{- if .Values.ingress.tls }}
  tls:
    {{- range .Values.ingress.tls }}
    - hosts:
        {{- range .hosts }}
        - {{ . | quote }}
        {{- end }}
      secretName: {{ .secretName }}
    {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
  rules:
    {{- range .Values.ingress.hosts }}
    - host: {{ .host | quote }}
      http:
        paths:
          {{- range .paths }}
          - path: /callista/?(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: amro-amroingres
                port: 
                  number: 8080
    {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
```

But, after I made the changes and tried to deploy using helm, I receive this error:
`Error: UPGRADE FAILED: current release manifest contains removed kubernetes api(s) for this kubernetes version and it is therefore unable to build the kubernetes objects for performing the diff. error from kubernetes: unable to recognize "": no matches for kind "Ingress" in version "networking.k8s.io/v1beta1"`

I am not sure why this error occurs even though the ingress manifest has changed and I have been stuck at this for a few days now. I am new to kubernetes and ingress in general, any help will be massively appreciated.

Comment: https://medium.com/@michael_33280/fixing-current-release-manifest-contains-removed-kubernetes-api-s-da6d948b651d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying out a lot more stuff I just decided to finally use helm unistall to remove the deployments and the charts currently in the cluster.

I then simply tried to install with the new ingress manifest which I have mentioned in the question and that worked out and was finally able to deploy. So, the manifest itself which I had modified did not have any issues it seems.

Answer (score 6):

The API resources on the Control plane are upgreaded but the ones in helm stored manifest (within a Secret resource) are old.

Here is the resolution:

```
$ helm plugin install https://github.com/helm/helm-mapkubeapis 
$ helm mapkubeapis my-release-name --namespace ns
```

After this run a `helm upgrade` again.

Answer (score 2):

Hi I had same problem one of the deployment was failing after we update our ingress files from apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1 to apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1 we had the same error with that app that was using helm

> UPGRADE FAILED: current release manifest contains removed kubernetes api(s) for this kubernetes version and it is therefore unable to build the kubernetes objects for performing the diff. error from kubernetes: unable to recognize "": no matches for kind "Ingress" in version "networking.k8s.io/v1beta1"

Here is the solution install the mapkubeapis plugin with helm by running the below cms in your terminal

```
helm plugin install <https://github.com/hickeyma/helm-mapkubeapis>
```

Downloading and installing helm-mapkubeapis v0.0.15 ...
https://github.com/hickeyma/helm-mapkubeapis/releases/download/v0.0.15/helm-mapkubeapis_0.0.15_darwin_amd64.tar.gz
Installed plugin: mapkubeapis

```
helm plugin list
```

NAME            VERSION DESCRIPTION
mapkubeapis     0.0.15  Map release deprecated Kubernetes APIs in-place

```
$ helm mapkubeapis release-name --namespace test-namespace --dry-run
```

the change the release-name to the name of your release/deployment that is failing. this cmd will list the files that have the old 1beta1

```
 helm mapkubeapis release-name --namespace test-namespace
```

finally run this above cmd that will update the files and remove the depreciation. now go to your pipeline and run the deployment again and it will work this time.

Comment: The last command is missing a space, mapkubeapis<space>release-name

Comment: @Sumukh thanks you are right the cmd should be as below:
 helm mapkubeapisr elease-name --namespace test-namespace

Comment: Make sure to refresh the plugin as new APIs are deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling and installing release worked for me.

```
1. helm uninstall <release>
2. helm install <release>
```

If you are doing the deployments through pipeline, you will have to manually perform step 1 and just re-trigger pipeline.